# Facebook signup and like a page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created a facebook login which I have tested and I can login to facebook it requests for information and then when I allow it I am registered. What I want to know is if there is a way to get the user to like a page upon registration without requesting posting rights? as on the site fancygiving.com I believe that when you register on their site you also like their facebook page.

I am not sure if this is useful but this App is purely for weblogin and is in development mode. Not sure if this makes a difference

Thanks

Comment: You can not like Facebook pages via API at all. (And doing so _automatically_ would be a violation of Platform Policies as well.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @CBroe has mentioned, you can not like Facebook pages via API **at all**.

Only thing that you can do to make your users like your facebook page is - add the [**Like Button**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/).